# How to execute a Command in Task

Tags: sbt

Is it possible to execute a Command in Sbt Task? If so, how? as Command requires a State, how could I obtain one?

I am trying to override a default task, here's what I've tried

```
dist := {
  println("Turning coverage off")
  Command.process("coverageOff")
  dist.value
}
```

The signature of `Command.process` is `(string, state) => _`

I havent figure out where to get the State

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can run a command within a task. Here is what I'm currently doing to achieve it. First, define the following method in your build:

```scala
/**
  * Convert the given command string to a release step action, preserving and      invoking remaining commands
  * Note: This was copied from https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release/blob/663cfd426361484228a21a1244b2e6b0f7656bdf/src/main/scala/ReleasePlugin.scala#L99-L115
  */
def runCommandAndRemaining(command: String): State => State = { st: State =>
  import sbt.complete.Parser
  @annotation.tailrec
  def runCommand(command: String, state: State): State = {
    val nextState = Parser.parse(command, state.combinedParser) match {
      case Right(cmd) => cmd()
      case Left(msg) => throw sys.error(s"Invalid programmatic input:\n$msg")
    }
    nextState.remainingCommands.toList match {
      case Nil => nextState
      case head :: tail => runCommand(head.commandLine, nextState.copy(remainingCommands = tail))
    }
  }
  runCommand(command, st.copy(remainingCommands = Nil)).copy(remainingCommands = st.remainingCommands)
}
```

Then, just call any command from within a task using the above defined utility, e.g., `runCommandAndRemaining("+myProject/publishLocal")(state.value)`.

In your specific case, it should boil down to

```scala
dist := {
  val log = streams.value.log
  log.debug("Turning coverage off")
  runCommandAndRemaining("coverageOff")(state.value)
  dist.value
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you add some explanation as to why this works? From what I understand, `runCommandAndRemaining` merely creates a new state where the desired command is pending. However, the resulting state is simply discarded in the definition of `dist`. Or is there some macro magic going on?

Comment: This also works for `Command.` definitions, if you just use `runCommandAndRemaining(state)`.

Answer (score 1):

[State](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Build-State.html#Using+State+in+a+task) can be obtained by evaluating `state.value`

> To access the current State from a task, use the `state` task as an
>   input. For example,
>
> `myTask := ... state.value ...`

and commands can be called within task using `Command.process` like so

```
dist := {
  println("Turning coverage off")
  Command.process("coverageOff", state.value)
  dist.value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting some help from gitter, it's not possible, one can however do the reverse, call a task in a command.

So if your use case is to run a command and a task sequentially (or vice versa), you can do something like this

```
lazy val newCommand = Command.command("name") { state =>
  val newState = Command.process("comandName", state)
  // run task
  newState
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is `Command.process`? It doesn't exist on the object and is giving symbol not resolved

Comment: Hi @boyang, this answer might be outdated, I think the accepted answer works, might worth to check that out

Comment: Turns out, `Command.process` was taken away in sbt 1.0.x and 1.1.x, but was added back in 1.2.x with a slightly different semantic. Your works again and should now be the correct answer