# Add a dependency for code in build.sbt (H2)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, h2

## Issue with Starting H2 Database Browser in Play Framework

I'm currently working with the Play Framework and have encountered an issue with starting the H2 database browser. Here's the background:

1. **Previous Setup:**

   - I used to start the H2 database browser using the terminal with the following commands:

     ```bash
     sbt
     h2-browser
     run
     ```
2. **Switched to IntelliJ:**

   - I later configured the Play application to run from IntelliJ, which improved my development workflow.
3. **H2 Browser Configuration:**

   - However, I faced a challenge with starting the H2 database browser within IntelliJ. To tackle this, I turned to ChatGPT for assistance.
4. **Adding H2 Dependency:**

   - I added the H2 dependency to the `build.sbt` file as follows:

     ```scala
     libraryDependencies += "com.h2database" % "h2" % "2.1.214"
     lazy val startH2Browser = taskKey[Unit]("Starts the H2 Browser")
     startH2Browser := {
       println("Starting H2 Browser...")
       org.h2.tools.Server.createWebServer("-web", "-webAllowOthers", "-webPort","8082").start()
     }

     playRunHooks += {
       new play.sbt.PlayRunHook {
         override def beforeStarted(): Unit = {
           startH2Browser.value
         }
       }
     }
     ```
5. **Encountered Error:**

   - Unfortunately, when I tried to start the H2 browser, I encountered the following error:

     ```
     build.sbt:55: error: object h2 is not a member of package org
       org.h2.tools.Server.createWebServer("-web", "-webAllowOthers", "-webPort", "8082").start()
           ^
     [error] Type error in expression
     Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
     ```
6. **Confirmation of H2 Package:**

   - I would like to confirm that SBT has successfully indexed and downloaded the H2 package. [image]

Can someone please advise me on how to properly import the H2 dependency in the `build.sbt` file and resolve this issue?

Comment: Note that if you already had a `h2-browser` command in SBT, you maybe could reuse it rather than reimplementing it. Unless I misunderstood your 1st bullet point and this is done outside of SBT.

Comment: @GaëlJ Yes, Looking for this only, I'm unsure about how to start that h2's browser server. can you tell how can i start that ?

Comment: Well, how do you start H2 in the 1st place?

Comment: Since it is mem based on JVM, it will be auto initated by play-framework based on config in application.conf

Comment: Okay. What I meant in my 1st comment is that maybe you should just be tying the `run` to the `h2-browser` command if it's already working fine. With something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183255/sbt-task-dependson

Comment: @GaëlJ Thanks Found that exactly how to run this command 
```lazy val startH2Browser = taskKey[Unit]("Starts the H2 Browser")
startH2Browser := {
  println("Starting H2 Browser...")
  Command.process("h2-browser", state.value)
}```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61376704/17974031.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by forking sbt command process and running `h2-browser`

```scala
lazy val startH2Browser = taskKey[Unit]("Starts the H2 Browser")
startH2Browser := {
  println("Starting H2 Browser...")
  Command.process("h2-browser",state.value)
}
playRunHooks += {
  new play.sbt.PlayRunHook {
    override def beforeStarted(): Unit = {
      startH2Browser.value
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the dependency to the "meta project".

SBT uses code to build your app. This code is itself "managed" and built by the "meta project" in the `project/` folder. *(And for the record, this is recursive, the meta project can have its meta meta project and so on!)*

To have a dependency available in the `build.sbt`, **you need to add a file `project/build-dependencies.sbt`** (the name doesn't matter but the extension does) with the dependency like following:

```scala
libraryDependencies += "com.h2database" % "h2" % "2.1.214"
```

You may then remove the same line that you added in the `build.sbt`. I guess you already had the dependency in `Test` scope somehow for the app itself.

Comment: Thanks, What i mentioned issue got fixed. But It create a new Web Server only. I'm already having one h2-db server how can i connect with that

Comment: @MohanaSundaramJ please open another question for this

Comment: Sure. I will open a new question for this